# Pygame object won't move when I take an OOP approach

Tags: python, class, oop, pygame

I am learning pygame and have created a little game where the knight has to get to the princess without running into the moving goblin. I was able to make this work just fine, however, when I try to take an OOP approach so that I can be efficient in later adding more goblins and such, there is no movement for the goblin, it is stationary. The parts that are commented out are the format in which this program works without using an OOP approach!!

```
import pygame


pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


pygame.display.set_caption("Get Princess")

icon = pygame.image.load('card-game.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


playerImg = pygame.image.load('knight.png')
playerImg = pygame.transform.scale(playerImg, (50,50))
playerX = 360
playerY = 520
playerX_change = 0
playerY_change = 0


princessImg = pygame.image.load('princess.png')
princessImg = pygame.transform.scale(princessImg, (50,50))
princessX = 360
princessY = 20

#Goblin Image
#goblinImg = pygame.image.load('goblin.png')
#goblinImg = pygame.transform.scale(goblinImg,(50,50))
#goblinX = 360
#goblinY = 250
#goblinX_change = 0.3

def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

def princess(x,y):
    screen.blit(princessImg, (x, y))


class goblin():
    def __init__(self, goblinX, goblinY):
        self.goblinX = goblinX
        self.goblinY = goblinY
        goblinImg = pygame.image.load('goblin.png')
        goblinImg = pygame.transform.scale(goblinImg,(50,50))
        screen.blit(goblinImg, (self.goblinX, self.goblinY))
        
    
    def movement(self, goblinX_change):
        self.goblinX_change = goblinX_change
        self.goblinX += self.goblinX_change
        if self.goblinX <= 0:
            self.goblinX_change += 0.3
        elif self.goblinX >= 750:
            self.goblinX_change = -0.3

    
running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((50,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
                    

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_change = -0.4
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 0.4
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.4
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.4
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change
    playerY += playerY_change


    #goblinX += goblinX_change
    #if goblinX <= 0:
        #goblinX_change += 0.3
    #elif goblinX >= 750:
        #goblinX_change = -0.3
    
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 750:
        playerX = 750
    if playerY <= 0:
        playerY = 0
    elif playerY >= 550:
        playerY = 550

    player(playerX,playerY)
    princess(princessX, princessY)
    #goblin(goblinX, goblinY)
    
    g = goblin(360,250)
    g.movement(0.3)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating goblin in the main loop every frame.

```
while running:  
    #ommited code
    g = goblin(360,250)
```

That means you are setting the position to `(360, 250)` every frame. Simple fix, make an instance once outside of the loop

```
g = goblin(360,250)
running = True
while running:
    #...
```

---

The goblin does not appear because you are drawing in `__init__`, but only calling it once. Give your goblin class a new method called `draw()` or something and do all the drawing in that method. Then call that method in the main loop.

```
class goblin():
    def __init__(self, goblinX, goblinY):
        self.goblinX = goblinX
        self.goblinY = goblinY
        self.goblinImg = pygame.image.load('goblin.png')
        self.goblinImg = pygame.transform.scale(goblinImg,(50,50))

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.goblinImg, (self.goblinX, self.goblinY))
    
    def movement(self, goblinX_change):
        self.goblinX_change = goblinX_change
        self.goblinX += self.goblinX_change
        if self.goblinX <= 0:
            self.goblinX += 0.3
        elif self.goblinX >= 750:
            self.goblinX = -0.3

g = goblin()
running = True
while running:
    #...
    g.movement()
    g.draw()
```

Comment: So I have tried this and now the goblin just does not appear at all. All I did was put the instance exactly how you showed, and even tried to run it with and without the original instance that is inside the loop. No luck...

Comment: It has initiated movement! Thank you! The thing is now it does not take into effect my boundaries that I have set up in my movement() function. I will attempt to fix this myself, but I appreciate any help you may want to provide!

Comment: @NickA Yep better to do it yourself as much as possible :-). Just a hint though, you are changing the wrong variable.

Comment: I have looked at this darn thing for a while now and I still can not understand why I would have to change a different variable. I am definitely stuck...

Comment: @NickA Well i can't tell for sure but I think your position value is represented by `self.goblinX` but  you are changing `self.goblinX_change`

Comment: @Nick Add `goblinX_change`  to `self.goblinX`. Maybe this would work: `if self.goblinX < 0: self.goblinX += goblinX_change`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222331/discussion-between-nicka-and-hippozhipos).